# Vertical badge deviates from edge with increasing text length

Tags: html, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a vertical "badge" aligned to the left / right edges of the browser. My current approach is to make a div and rotate it 90 degrees, then use `position: fixed; left: 0; top: 20%` to place it properly, however I've ran into the following problem:

As the text grows longer, the widget becomes "detached" from the left and right edges of the browser.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/bv3no599/ (See how the badges deviate further with longer text)

**Current Code**:

```
<div id="badge-outer-2" style="background: #1508bc;color:#FFFFFF;position: fixed;border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 5px;transform:rotate(90deg);top: 50%;padding:8px;font-size:13px;box-shadow:0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);z-index:99996;cursor:pointer; left: -50px">Not OK when the text is longer and longer</div>
```

Could anyone point me to a solution to this problem? Why does it move farther from the edge after increasing the text length?

Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice to put your CSS in the CSS tab within JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotation of an element is by default based on its center. By just using `transform: rotate(90deg)` you will rotate it 90 degrees around its center axis. That causes the edges of the different size elements to end up on different places.

Instead, try rotating around the lower left corner:

```
transform-origin: 0 100%;
```

Now both elements will be close to the left edge of the screen no matter how tall they are, but your hardcoded `left` offset messes it up a bit. Instead, just position them at `left: 0;` to always stick them to the left hand of the screen. This way you also don't have to set a new offset for each element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bv3no599/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using

```
left: -22px;
```

and

```
left: -50px;
```

to manually correct a certain side-effect of rotations. Namely, rotations by default rotate with respect to the *center* of the element, therefore leaving you with spaces to the sides. What's happening is that when you "undershoot" your correction relative to the text length, *e.g.* `-50px`, you get that detachment—try changing it to `-80px` or `-100px` to see what I mean. (If you "overshoot," the text disappears altogether.)

Instead, use

```
transform-origin: left bottom;
```

to rotate from the appropriate origin, and set

```
left: 0;
```

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/rkxuu8cs/1/.